# Only part of a string is displayed

Tags: javascript

In the code below I'm trying to output the date and print text you have type in. The datetime works as it does display but when I implemented the print function it outputs "ime".

The print function works when you type "print" and what ever else after. Example, input "print hi there" output "hi there". Any feedback would be much appreciated.

```
<html>
    <body>

    <div id="out" name="out"></div>

    <script type="text/JavaScript">
    function theProcess(){      
        alert("> Your typed "+enter);
    }

    function datetime(){
        var enter = "";
        var currentdate = new Date(); 
        var datetime = "Date and Time today: " + currentdate.getDate() + "/"
            + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
            + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "  
            + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
            + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
            + currentdate.getSeconds();

        if (enter == 'datetime')
        {
            alert(datetime)
        }
        else
        {
            alert(" You typed, "+enter);
        }
    }

    </script>

    <script type="text/JavaScript"> 

    function addOutput(s){
        document.getElementById("out").innerHTML=document.getElementById("out").innerHTML+s+"\n";
    }

    // turns a string into an array and displays it

    var enter = '';
    enter = prompt('enter text')
    var str = "print a b c d";
    var list = str.split(" ");
    for(i=0; i<list.length;i++){
        var message=list[i];
        switch(message){

        case "print":
            alert(message.substring(5))

        }
    }



    </script>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please indent your code correctly

Comment: You'll understand better if you look up the meanings of [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Fsplit) and [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Fsubstring).  Also, if you that doesn't help, just `alert(message)` in `case "print"`, and think about substring then.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure you want `var list = enter.split(" ");`, as you're currently ignoring what the user types.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var str = "print a b c d";
        // print every single argument after "print" with a single alert
        var list = str.split(" ");
        for(i=1; i<list.length; i++){
            var message=list[i];
            switch(list[0]){
                case "print":
                    alert(message)
            }
        }
        // print all arguments after "print" with a single alert
        // var list = str.split(" ");
        if(list[0] == "print") {
            list.shift();
            alert(list.join(" "));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down this command parser. You split str into parts at spaces:

```
var str = "print a b c d";
var list = str.split(" ");
```

Now list contains the array `["print", "a", "b", "c", "d"]`. Next you're looping through each of those five elements of the array and putting the element into the message variable.

```
for(i=0; i<list.length;i++){
    var message=list[i];
```

Then you act on the command in each part:

```
    switch(message){
    case "print":
```

If I understand correctly, this is wrong. You don't want a loop here. Get rid of the loop and just do `switch (list[0]) {`

For the print command, you print `message.substring(5)`. You seem to have muddled your variables. `message` is just "print" at this point, so `message.substring(5)` is going to be empty. You probably meant `str.substring(6)` (to trim off the "print ").

Comment: Even easier than split and the loop: `if (str.indexOf("print") == 0) alert(str.substring(6));`